# check boolean type after checkbox is selected

Tags: jquery, checkbox, boolean, iteration

Im trying to check value `true` , but doesnt works, Im little confused, does anyobody have idea where Im did mistake? Thank you

```
function upd_11_checkDividing(upd_11_whatIsClicked){
    var upd_11_settedKorpus = parseInt( upd_11_whatIsClicked +1 );
    var upd_11_inputId = '#checkbox_divider_'+upd_11_settedKorpus;
    var upd_11_settedCheckbox = jQuery(upd_11_inputId).is(':checked');

    if ( upd_11_settedCheckbox === true) {alert;};
    upd_11_arrayDividedSectionBoolean[upd_11_whatIsClicked] = upd_11_settedCheckbox;

    // upd_11_arrayDividedSectionBoolean works very well true/false;
}
```

* variable upd_11_whatIsClicked is known, it is index ...

Comment: What exactly is going wrong? And if you create a jsfiddle it might be easier for us to test your code.

Comment: Thank you for your time, next I will try to create jsfiddle. Ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**alert** is a function with parameter *message* and you are using it like that:

```
alert;
```

try to change it to something like

```
alert('checkbox selected');
```

Comment: Oh, stupid me, doesnt see the alert() , but waited the alert window, sry. Thank you